# Code not working in firefox while runs fine in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, locale

how and why does the following piece of code giving 1 in chrome while it gives 2 in firefox.

```
    var a = "2014/04/27"
    var b =  "2014/04/09"
    var n = a.localeCompare(b);
    console.log(n);
```

I am using the above code in my project and it runs fine in chrome but buggy in firefox. Any suggestions or equivalent functions for the above work is welcome. Thank You.......

Comment: Why not creating JS-Date object

Comment: @pc-shooter yeah i can but i want to know why this locale compare method is not working in firefox while it is supported by firefox

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function implementation differs for one browser to another.

Here is the documentation page for Firefox : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare ...

... and see this thread for more infos : http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=459

Comment: hey in older versions of firefox the output is like -2, -1 -3 but in firefox 29 it is like chrome 0,1, and -1 :)